# Password field name change in Drupal7

Tags: drupal-7

How to rename the registration password field in drupal7?

Comment: You need to alter that using hook_form_alter().

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the hook [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7). There are a lot of tutorial on how to use form_alter to change form elements, for exemple this [one](http://www.chromaticsites.com/blog/drupal-tutorial-form-overrides-and-element-specific-validations/) (randomly found)